# Makefile many similar files

Tags: makefile

With many similar files in a directory:

```
answer1.c
answer2.c
answer3.c
```

To be able to run:

```
# make s1
# ./answer1
```

Currently I have:

```
s1:
    gcc -Wall -ansi answer1.c -o answer1
s2:
    gcc -Wall -ansi answer2.c -o answer2
```

etc.

I know I can put the compiler and the flags in variables, which makes changing things later easier. However, is there a way (some kind of macro expansion) to automate, something like:

```
#=1 2 3 4 5 6
s#:
    gcc -Wall -ansi answer#.c -o answer#
```

Or even better

```
#=range(7)
```

Or would I be better off using a scripting language, perhaps to write the Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html):

```
s%: answer%
answer%: answer%.c
     gcc -Wall -ansi $< -o $@
```

Issue `make -p | less` (at least with GNU make) and you will see that `make` already has built-in rules very similar to that.

Comment: It looks like this will work even better than the first answer, thank you for adding this information.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use just 3 lines of `makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi

all: answer1 answer2 answer3
```

With that, you can simply run `make` and it knows what you want it to do: it will create program `answer1` from `answer1.c`, and program `answer2` from `answer2.c`, and program `answer3` from `answer3.c`.

To build any one of the programs, simply say:

```
make answer2
```

Etc.

Comment: That would compile all of them though wouldn't it? Perhaps I should be clearer in my question that I need each to be a separate, exclusive target

Comment: See my update, typed while you were asking.  The default target builds them all; you can build any one of them.  If you don't want the default target to build anything, then you can use: `default:` as the target name and the action `@echo "You must specify a target to build"`.  This is what I do in my directories full of single-file programs (the one for SO questions, and my `cmd` directory, to name but two).  Alternatively, if you want `answer1` created by default, then simply use `answer1:` and `answer2:` and `answer3:` as the three targets in the file.

Comment: Thank you, clearly I was missing the basics there. To be 100% complete, is there a simple way to specify a range of values to avoid typing in all n filenames?

Comment: Now that's harder...`make $(seq -f 'answer%g' 3 6)` making the shell and the `seq` program do the work.  Checked on Mac OS X 10.9.3; will probably work on Linux too.

Comment: Note that if you really want to type the program name to be compiled each time, you could make do with a one-line `makefile` containing simply `CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi`.  Then you can type `make anything` and if there's a source file `anything.X` for an X extension that `make` knows how to compile into a program, it will do so with no further help from you.  That can be quite useful, sometimes.  In particular, it means you can use the `makefile` with `answer1` through `answer6` listed in it and still use it to create `something-else` from `something-else.c`, etc.

Comment: GNU Make also has various functions for file name and general string manipulation. `all: $(patsubst %,answer%,1 2 3)`